# Can't make UDP connections between Windows 10 and Android on DLAN

Tags: networking, windows-10, android, powerline-networking

I have a Windows 10 PC connected via LAN to a DLAN (aka powerline) adapter. The same DLAN adapter also is a Wifi Hotspot where Androids connect to.

The opposing DLAN adapter is connected via LAN to a DSL router.

PC and Android are on the same Subnet.

**No matter what I try I'm unable to connect several, completely different, Android Remote Apps to the Windows 10 PC.** Each app communicates via a fixed UDP port.

I tried to

- turn off Windows Firewall
- open UDP Ports in the Router (makes not much sense cause this is for internet connections, but anyway)
- allow Multicast etc.
- allow UPNP
- allow each client to open UDP ports

I have no idea why it's not working. I also have e.g. a Linux-VSFTP Server on the same DLAN adapter (via LAN) and there're no connection issues with any client.

**How can I debug this?**

Comment: Are you saying the Android device can connect to the SFTP server?

Comment: Yes, all my Androids can connect to the local FTP server without any problems. It all started with Windows 10, first I had to replace SMB with FTP cause I was unable to make a SMB connection, tried for weeks. (Same topic, different story) Now this UDP problem. I'm going mad, I'm not that bad with networking but I cannot get this to work.

Comment: The SMB problem may have been a version thing, an older protocol.  But if I were you I'd be breaking out wireshark to see what exactly is going on with UDP.

Comment: Wireshark shows the UDP port in question is on the wrong subnet. That subnet doesn't exist in my network. Why? How? How to fix?

Comment: It was VBox Network adapter.. :|

Answer (score 0):

**Use Wireshark to look up the UDP port.**

In this particular case the UDP port was on a different subnet. Checking network adapters I found that the receiving Windows software tried to use VirtualBox Network Adapter instead of the real one.

(If anyone wants to post a more detailed step-by-step answer I will mark his / her answer as solution)

Comment: Hi Lee - you did the step by step, it would be great if you could expand on this answer to help others.